# Unable to Simulate HTTP 302 response

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, payment-gateway

I'm trying to incorporate PagSeguro (a payment gateway - Brazil's version of PayPal) into my site. After the customer finishes with PagSeguro, they send data (via POST) to a function which I specify. However, I'm not receiving the POST. After doing all the troubleshooting I could think of, I contacted PagSeguro. They said that their log indicates that the POST is being sent as normal but they are receiving an HTTP 302 response.

In order to figure out why this is happening, I created a form with hidden values to simulate sending a POST to my function. I put this form under a different domain just in case it had something to do with that. Every time I send the POST from my simulation form, I receive an HTTP 200 response, and my log indicates that the POST was received.

How is it possible that PagSeguro is receiving a different response than my simulation? Could it have something to do with the server or is it something to do with my script?

Here is the function (using CodeIgniter) that should be receiving the POST:

```
function pagseguro_retorno(){
    if (count($_POST) == 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $msg = 'POST RECEIVED';
    $simulate = $this->input->post('Simulate');
    if ( ! empty($simulate)){
        $result = 'VERIFICADO';
        $msg .= ' FROM SIMULATOR';
    } else {
        $this->load->library(PagSeguroNpi);
        $result = $this->PagSeguroNpi->notificationPost();
    }
    $this->log($msg);
    if ($result == "VERIFICADO") {
        $id = $this->input->post('Referencia');//cart id
        $this->load->model('transacao_model');
        $trans_row = $this->transacao_model->get_transaction($id);
        if ( ! is_object($trans_row)){
            //LOAD NEW TRANSACTION
            if ( ! $this->new_transaction($id)){
                $notice = "Unable to load new transaction</p><p>";
                $this->log($notice);
                $notice .= '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, TRUE).'</pre>';
                $this->email_notice($notice);
            }
        }
        $this->load->model('carrinho_model');
        if($_POST['StatusTransacao'] == 'Aprovado'){
            $status = 'apr';
        }elseif($_POST['StatusTransacao'] == 'Em Análise'){
            $status = 'anl';
        }elseif($_POST['StatusTransacao'] == 'Aguardando Pagto'){
            $status = 'wtg';
        }elseif($_POST['StatusTransacao'] == 'Completo'){
            $status = 'cmp';
            //nothing more happens here - client must click on 'mark as shipped' before cart is removed and history data is loaded
        }elseif($_POST['StatusTransacao'] == 'Cancelado'){
            //reshelf - don't set $status, because the cart's about to be destroyed
            $this->carrinho_model->reshelf(array($id));
        }
        if (isset($status)){
            $this->carrinho_model->update_carrinho($id, array('status' => $status));
        }
    } else if ($result == "FALSO") {
        $notice = "PagSeguro return was invalid.";
        $this->log($notice);
        $notice .= '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, TRUE).'</pre>';
        $this->email_notice($notice);
    } else {
        $notice = "Error in PagSeguro request";
        $this->log($notice);
        $notice .= '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, TRUE).'</pre>';
        $this->email_notice($notice);
    }
}
```

SECURITY UPDATE:

After posting, I soon realized that I was opening myself up to hack attempts. The function necessarily has to be public, so anyone who knows the name of the function could access it and post 'simulate' to get immediate verification. Then they could pass whatever data they wanted.

I changed the name of the function to something that would be impossible to guess, and when not in production mode, I've disabled the simulate option.

Comment: Have you tried logging the requests to make sure PagSeguro is in fact requesting the correct page? It's better to be sure.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you mean to log the request, but there is no doubt that they are requesting the correct page. I've verified the URL several times.

Comment: I mean in the apache logs, google analytics, your php application, wherever you want. Write each request to a log file with the HTTP_REFERER, the URL requested, and GET/POST params to make sure it's correct. If you are *100% sure* they are requesting the right URL with the right params, then nevermind - but I would err on the side of caution and just make sure.

Comment: I looked at the access logs for the site and the URLs are identical. The one from PagSeguro shows an HTTP 302 response and the one from my simulation shows an HTTP 200 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my CSRF protection causes a redirect when the proper CSRF code isn't sent with the POST. My simulator was working, because I copied the HTML generated by a dynamic simulator that I made on the site in question. I then pasted the HTML to create a static simulator and put it under a different URL. Along with the HTML, I inadvertently pasted the CSRF code as well. The static simulator worked fine until the code expired. I quit using it after a couple times, so I didn't discover that it was no longer working until today.

I know that this exact scenario probably won't happen again in the next 500 years, but things like CSRF security can cause problems with things like payment gateways if not disabled for the function receiving the POST.